# Unexpected token error when using Vue-pdf

Tags: laravel, webpack, single-page-application, vue-pdf

I'm creating an SPA with Laravel and Vue and am trying to use vue-pdf.  I've successfully integrated several npm packages, but this one is giving me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

When I click on the file (worker.js) in my console, it looks like it's trying to perform a get request for a regular page on my site instead of grabbing the javascript so my hunch is that webpack isn't correctly transpiling vue-pdf.  My current webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
require('laravel-mix-versionhash')
// const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist/css')
  .sass('resources/sass/flowy.scss', 'public/dist/css')

mix.babel([
  'resources/js/helpers/Date.js',
  'resources/js/helpers/LoginRedirect.js'
], 'public/assets/js/combined.js')

  .disableNotifications()

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix
    // .extract() 
    // .version() 
    .versionHash()
} else {
  mix.sourceMaps()
}

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/js')
    }
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'dist/js/[chunkhash].js',
    path: mix.config.hmr ? '/' : path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build')
  }
})

mix.then(() => {
  if (!mix.config.hmr) {
    process.nextTick(() => publishAseets())
  }
})

function publishAseets () {
  const publicDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')

  if (mix.inProduction()) {
    fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'dist'))
  }

  fs.copySync(path.join(publicDir, 'build', 'dist'), path.join(publicDir, 'dist'))
  fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'build'))
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example repository to look at?

Comment: Do you mean the vue-pdf repository?  If so: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf

Comment: No I meant like a minimal working example based on your code that reproduces the error.

Comment: OK! I've just created one where you won't have to log in: https://dev.adapt.libretexts.org/pdf-test.  And on my live server I'm getting a different error  (though probably the same issue) --- Refused to execute script from 'https://dev.adapt.libretexts.org/5142c4e99f64f9a427e6.worker.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Is this helping you? https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/13#issuecomment-458482205

Comment: That page helps in the sense that it does seem like it's a loader issue.  However, I'm still not quite sure how to implement the fix with my own webpack config.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with webpack configs, but the error you're getting is because like you mentioned, your worker.js is returned as regular HTML page. MIME type mismatch is also saying the same. This is happening because the the file doesn't exist on that location, and your Laravel application is giving the [page not found](https://dev.adapt.libretexts.org/5142c4e99f64f9a427e6.worker.js). So the root cause could be your webpack config as your build files aren't right. I've just tried vue-pdf on a project and I've no issues, but then my webpack.mix.js is a lot simpler. Perhaps try the default

Comment: Would you mind sharing your config?

Comment: Oh, my config is same as the [default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js) :)

Comment: I originally updated my answer saying that the minimal config helped.  I fear that I hadn't restarted my server, and re-run npm run watch.  Once I did, a whole slew of other errors popped up.  So, I think I still need to figure out how to use my current webpack config with some sort of modification.

Comment: I've looked over the repository alongside their existing issues and stumbled across [this](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/13). Seems like your issue may be common based on the repository.

Comment: But you're not using SSR or Nuxt, are you? @Eric

Comment: I'm using neither SSR nor Nuxt I'm afraid.  @skyez

Comment: This question needs more explanation.  I just installed vue-pdf on a laravel project with mix and it transpiles correctly.  My worker.js filename is prefixed with a hash.  If you are getting an HTML page with 404 when requesting worker.js, perhaps it is not being built or it is prefixed with a compile-time hash.

Comment: I think that your idea is a reasonable one.  Unfortunately I'm a super noob with webpack and am not sure how to check if it is either of those issues.  Some guidance would be appreciated.  @chugadie

Comment: Eric, you have to search your hard drive for a file named "worker.js" or "\*worker\*" and see where it is, or if it exists at all.  Then you'll know the problem is either "no worker.js is being built" or "worker.js is in the wrong place" or "my manifest is wrong"